# Using the Object Capture API with the camera of the Android device

Tags: android-camera, arkit, photogrammetry, usdz

Can I take photos from an android device or any camera instead of an ipad or iphone while using the Object Capture API? What negative side effects can it have.

Note: I'm asking this question because I noticed that the size of the usdz model has grown too much in my experiments. (For example 200mb instead of 20mb)

Comment: After converting to usdz2obj, I produced a temporary solution by decrease the resolution of the textures.